# Why is there a UUID attached to each object identity?

Tags: csom, site-collection, site, guid

I am using CSOM to access sharepoint objects, and I need unique identifiers for site collections, webs, lists, and list items.

So when you have an object identify for example for a site collection, it will look something like this:

`0569d79e-5569-2024-65bd-6486b22763a8|740c6a0b-85e2-48a0-a494-e0f1759d4aa7:site:7422c68a-06c9-41ca-ac61-b2ea24c0f6b2:web:5e4ff74d-4416-4de1-8a68-d4d733e82b00`

- `740c6a0b-85e2-48a0-a494-e0f1759d4aa7` - is the web application GUID
- `7422c68a-06c9-41ca-ac61-b2ea24c0f6b2` - is the site collection GUID
- `5e4ff74d-4416-4de1-8a68-d4d733e82b00` - is the web GUID

But why is there a prefix of `0569d79e-5569-2024-65bd-6486b22763a8|`? What's the point of that? Even more confusing, this prefix is unique every time you request metadata.